# Find out whether UITableView is scrolled to top

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` to scroll UITableView to top. Then I handle the animation in `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`. After it scrolls, it should perform an action. My problem is, that when it doesn't scroll - e.g. the table view is already on top before I call the method - the action doesn't get called in `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`. How do I find out whether the UITableView is already on top?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (yourTableView.contentOffset.y > 0)
{
    // yourTableView is not on top.
}
else
{
    // yourTableView is already on top.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use UITableView **contentOffset** property. If `contentOffset.y` is 0 then table is at top else it is not.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the UIScrollViewDelegate function `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView` and work out if the content offset is set to 0 on the y axis for that scrollview. If its 0 then you have reached the top.

Answer (score 0):

while you're scrolling up `tableView(_:cellForRowAt)` gets called to display rows and when the `indexPath.row == 0` that's when you're at the top of the tableview